# Why <%= Html.TextArea("Id",Model)%> shows as an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp.net MVC. When I declear this code then an error shows. Why this is showing and how can i solve it? Thank you.

This is my code :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer","Customer",FormMethod.Post))
{ %>
    Enter customer id :- <%= Html.TextArea("Id",Model)%> <br /> //shows error
    <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
<%} %>
```

Error message :

CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'TextArea' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Your `Model` appears to be of type `dynamic`. You should declare it to be of a specific type instead.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Or it isn't a strongly typed view. Not sure if MVC uses `dynamic` as the type in the backend when it isn't strongly typed, so it might be synonymous with your statement. Should casting it to its intended type then not fix it? (Although I'd still suggest going for a strongly typed approach then)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you aren't providing the TextArea method with the right parameters. The second parameter of the TextArea overload that you are matching is called HtmlAttributes and it is of type Object. It is meant to take the html attributes you might provide your text area, such as an id, class name, readonly, or disabled. You are providing it with a Model that, while an object, probably isn't providing the text area with html attributes.

You should use TextAreaFor like this

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x=> x.id)%>
```

Try looking up some info on Mvc Forms. It should explain how to use them better than I would.

Comment: `TextArea` and `TextAreaFor` are not always interchangeable; it depends on how well constructed the viewmodels are. Given that it's a likely option that the entire view isn't strongly typed (awaiting confirmation from OP), this answer might not be a solution for the problem.

Comment: This answer is wrong. htmlAttributes parameter does not require you to have id, class, name or any other property inside. It works as key-value pair and can contain any value. And while it may render incorrect attributes on client side, it would not cause compile exception

Comment: It might not be correct, but I guess we will see. TextArea and TextAreaFor aren't interchangeable, but I am betting on TextAreaFor. He has some Model that has an ID property and he wants it to be included in that model when he submits the form. Also I know by virtue of the fact that is of type Object that it will accept pretty much anything as htmlAttributes, but it wont render correctly. Unless his model is truly a Dynamic, I think my answer would solve his problem.